# Upgrade from 10 to 11, last major release and are there plans to charge for updates?

Tags: windows-11

Seems like Ive heard this before - "this will be the last major release of windows" etc.
Im in the process of checking out the reviews of 11 before updating my Windows 10 workstation at home.  Will microsoft release updates to 11 the same way it always has or start charging for them, aka some sort of subscription?

Comment: You might confuse Windows 11 for Microsoft Azure Desktop, their subscription where you can rent desktop space. There also have been plans to do a Windows as a Service, which is basically the same thing as MS Azure Desktop.

Comment: Isn’t Azure Desktop marketed towards Enterprise?  Renting a Windows instance, in the cloud is not a new concept, certainly something that Nvidia has proven is desired with their cloud gaming services. However, how those instances are licensed, are linked to an enterprise level contract. Microsoft will switch to a subscription model for Windows after Apple switches their model for MacOS.  Microsoft makes virtually no money when it comes to individual Windows licenses.  The money that the OS department makes, is being made from OEM licenses at huge scales, and MSDN subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had Windows 11 running for 5 months (Insider) and 1 month (Production).

There has been no indication in the Insider News that Microsoft is going to start charging consumers and small business (OEM Computers) for updates. The last time I looked (recent Desktop purchase) OEM Pro upgrade is $40 or $50 US Dollars and that is just the upgrade, not the basic Home license).  And then remember OEM licenses die with the machine and cannot be transferred. So Microsoft does make money here.

Nor was there any indication in MVP meetings I attended in Redmond in 3 different years.

New computers for Consumers (always) and small / medium business (mostly) come with OEM operating systems that manufacturers pay Microsoft for.

Large businesses often use Volume Licensing which may or may not involve a subscription model.

So for most of us individuals and small businesses, it should very likely be the same as always.

Remember (and unlike the "News") manufacturers and software vendors generally do not publish "We are NOT doing this (e.g. charging for OS " articles.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has not announced plans to stop supporting Windows 10, and enterprise users have been told to continue using it.

Windows 11 is currently testing new features that will not be added to Windows 10.  Not everyone likes the new features, but they seem to be getting better from user feedback.  So if you like trying new things and want to give Microsoft feedback, you may find Windows 11 interesting.

Even with the existence of Windows 11, it is unclear that Windows 10 is not the "last" version -- this may still be true, in the sense that there is no need to abandon Windows 10 just because Windows 11 exists.

Microsoft has not announced any plans to change their charging structure for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like I've heard this before - "this will be the last major release of windows" etc.

It appears that this statement was made by a singular Microsoft employee, an employee whom didn't have in-depth knowledge, of what the future of Windows was going to be.  Microsoft never actually repeated that statement, and looking backwards, Windows 10 was supported for 5 years before Microsoft announced to Windows 11.  This matches the lifespan of Windows 8 that came before it. I do realize that Windows 10 version 21H2 is supported for 5 years.

> Will Microsoft release updates to 11 the same way it always has?

Microsoft through a blog article, has confirmed, that they are only going to release yearly feature updates for Windows 11.  This means the next version of Windows 11  will be `Windows 11 version 22H2`.  They have also indicated that Windows 10 version 21H2, might see more substantial updates, then we originally thought.  Microsoft has slightly backtracked on the statement, through indirect actions and statements within blog articles, that Windows 10 version 20H2 would be the last supported version of Windows 10.

> start charging for them, aka some sort of subscription?

**Microsoft has never indicated in it's entire company history any desire to charge a monthly subscription for Windows to individual users of Windows.**  They have of course, updated what was already a subscription based model, if you are an Enterprise to offer multiple different options.  Anyone attempting to scare you into thinking that Windows will transition to a subscription model, for the end consumer, is attempting to scare you by telling you a tall tale.